# .htaccess redirect when domain name is unknown

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site that I am not sure what the domain name will eventually be when it's live, but as I am working on it I access it through a local server. One of the directories on the site needs to be redirected. To save time when the site goes live (and also just to learn how) I am trying to write a .htaccess statement that will redirect the directory regardless of what the domain name is. Currently I access the site through:

```
http://phuk9220/
```

I want this directory:

```
/audio/help-and-faqs/
```

to redirect to:

```
/audio/help-and-faqs/welcome/
```

Now, I can easily do this with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/audio/help-and-faqs/$ http://phuk9220/audio/help-and-faqs/welcome/
```

However, it means changing the **http://phuk9220/** to whatever domain will it will eventually be on. Is there anyway of changing the domain dynamically depending on where it actually is ?

Thanks in advance and if you have any questions, please ask.

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omitting the domain name entirely should do the redirect on the same domain that was requested.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/audio/help-and-faqs/$ /audio/help-and-faqs/welcome/
```

Comment: Lol, I was thinking about it too much. Thanks for the help, nitro2k01 - that worked great :) What about getting to to redirect to the welcome directory if the "/" is ommitted from the ^/audio/help-and-faqs/$ ?